# Tracking of views on UIWIndow In iOS app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

WHen we use navigation controller as a root of window and we pushed multiple controllers on that navigation controller. lets say 
A as navigation controller
B as root of navigation controller
C is pushed on B
D is pushes on C

then what will be hierarchi of views on window.
is it like first Window -> A -> B -> C -> D;

or they  are in memory but on window there is only one D?

Comment: Debug->ViewDebugging->Capture View Hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do investigation by your own, just print during debug :

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

It will show you full View hierarchy for your app.

But yes, the final structure looks like:

UIWindow -> UINavigationController.view -> RootViewController.view -> OtherViewControllerView -> Subview's